# Cake PHP redirection

Tags: cakephp-2.1

CakePHP redirection of url like *.php
 My site is integrated with more than 20 other sites. 
They have a url to access my site
Now i rewrite my code in CakePHP .
So i want to redirect the old urls to the corresponding cakePHP page

Answer (score 0):

You may use the routes configuration to add some paths that resolve your current urls sending them to the appropriate action:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

However, I think you should manage that situation directly in your web server whatever it be (apache, nginx, etc).

Comment: in routes there is no option for redirecting www.example.com/service.php?comid=1 to www.example.com/service/viewservice/1